# Не обновляется информация в textarea VUE

Tags: vue.js

Есть массив `cards` с содержанием

```
{ id:1, note: "Text1"}
{ id:2, note: "Text2"}
```

Выводим этот массив в шаблон, `note` выводим в `textarea` и в `div`

```
<textarea @keyup="setNote($event, card.id)" cols="34" rows="3">{{card.note}}</textarea>
<div>{{card.note}}</div>
```

Так же добавим кнопку, после нажатия на которую у нас будет заменяться массив `cards`

```
test: function() {
  this.cards = [
    { id:1, note: "Новый текст 1"},
    { id:2, note: "Новый текст 2"},
  ];
}
```

Если в первом `textarea` заменить `Text1` например на `text1111` и нажать на кнопку `Test` то первое `textarea` останется неизменным(text1111), хотя текст должен замениться на `Новый текст 1`, в `div` меняется

Если `textarea` не трогать и нажать на `Test`, то текст меняется

[Тест на jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4gvw1fz5/)

Как изменить данные в `textarea` при нажатии на кнопку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использовать `<textarea v-model="card.note"></textarea>` вместо `<textarea>{{card.note}}</textarea>`